# how to receive parameters in an angular app 8 from an external site

Tags: angular, url, parameters, router

I have two angular applications and I need to go from one to another taking a token as a parameter, I tried it via localStorage but it doesn't stay, in an angular application I just put the parameters in index.html and it could keep it (example: `"localhost: 4200 /index.html?test=test "`), but when doing the same thing with angular8 it indicates this console error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'index.html'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'index.html'
```

Router of the application that will receive the parameters:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ContentComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'home', component: ContentComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'files', component: FilesComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'views', component: VisualizesComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'refresh', component: RefreshComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

As I open the other application:

```
 window.open("http://localhost:4200/login?_t=" + token);
```

Comment: can you share more code? like router configurations for both?